# How can my Sinatra API manage user logins in client apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, session, sinatra

I'm building an API using Sinatra, which should be able to manage the user login sessions for any of the client apps that send requests to it. So far (for the login functionality) what I've got is a route for /login, and if the User credentials are valid, an AccessToken is created in the RDBMS. See below:

```
    #
    # Login
    #
    post '/login' do
      if (@input["email"].nil? || @input["password"].nil?) then
        response = {
          "success" => false,
          "msg" => "Email and password must be provided"
        }
        $log.error "Email or password not sent to /login"
        return response.to_json
      end

      email     = @input["email"]
      password  = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(@input["password"])

      user = User.where(:email => email, :password => password).first
      if user.nil?
        response = {
          "success" => false,
          "msg" => "No users exist with that email/password combo"
        }
        $log.error "Invalid Email or Password sent to /login"
        return response.to_json
      end

      token = AccessToken.new(:user_id => user.id)
      token.save!

      $log.info "User valid. Logged in. Token: #{token.token}"
      response = {
        "success" => true,
        "msg" => "User logged in",
        "data" => {"token" => token.token}
      }
      return response.to_json
    end
```

Then for any other routes that require authentication, I'm checking if the token is being sent as a param with the request, e.g.:

```
    #
    # Return Clients for User
    #
    # get '/clients/:token' do
    get '/clients' do
      token = AccessToken.where(:token => params[:token]).first
      @current_user = User.find(token.user_id) unless token.nil?

      if @current_user.nil?
        response = {
          "success" => false,
          "msg" => "User must be logged in to do this"
        }
        $log.error "User is not logged in"
        return response.to_json
      end

      response = {
        "success" => true,
        "msg" => "Clients successfully retrieved",
        "data" => {"clients" => @current_user.clients}
      }
      $log.info "Clients successfully retrieved"
      return response.to_json
    end
```

So I'm wondering: (a) is this a good/robust way of handling user sessions with an API, and (b) is there a standard way of handling it on the client side (iOS, Android, and Web apps)? Should they perhaps store the access token in a session variable, and then with every request add the token to the params being sent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look into JSON Web Tokens for a standardized way of exchanging tokens: http://jwt.io/

For the Sinatra part, you could use the following pattern to keep yourself from repeating the authorization code:

```
before do
  token = AccessToken.where(:token => params[:token]).first
  @current_user = User.find(token.user_id) unless token.nil?
end
```

Register an auth method:

```
register do
  def auth (type)
    condition do
      return {
        "success" => false,
        "msg" => "User must be logged in to do this"
      }.to_json unless @current_user
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can add this requirement to any route:

```
get '/clients', :auth => :user do
  # Your implementation
end
```